# Redis in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, redis

I am running Redis on Ubuntu. When I run the Redis commands, I get a error saying "redis server not found in "redis/src". I have copy pasted the `redis-server.exe` files on to the Ubuntu machine. What could be the reason for this?

Comment: Note that `redis-server.exe` probably only runs on a Windows machine. Most programs on Unix do not use a `.exe` extension at all (though they work OK if they're compiled for the Unix machine and you invoke them including the `.exe` in the name you run).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy-pasting doesn't work.
Just follow this link http://redis.io/download and install the Redis.
Later just change the `redis-2.8.9` folder name to `redis`. Should be simple and should work in your case.

Comment: An alternative to renaming is `cd /opt; ln -s redis-2.8.9 redis` (where I'm assuming the software is installed in `/opt`, with the executables in `/opt/redis-2.8.9/bin`, etc).  The advantage of this is that you can install an upgrade in `/opt/redis-2.9.1`, say, and then switch between the two versions by simply removing the old symlink and creating a new one.  This includes reverting back to the old version if there's a problem with the new.  If there's a lot of data stored under the `redis` directory, then you have to work harder, but for many systems, this technique is good.

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you just run apt command

```
apt-get install redis-server
```

for details you can visit this page:

https://library.linode.com/databases/redis/ubuntu-12.04-precise-pangolin

Answer (score 0):

.exe runs in windows. You need to install redis as per ubuntu server.

Download stable release of redis from [here](https://redis.io/download).
Just follow these simple [steps](http://www.zippyout.com/blog/58e7e44e46aa1f0292fb77ff/Install-Redis-Ubuntu-14.04-or-Ubuntu-16.04-and-Redis-Authentication) to install redis.